# Hide Layered Navigation Attribute if only 1 available

Tags: attributes, layered-navigation

My store has numerous attributes in my layered navigation to allow customers to refine the product views/searches. On some of my categories i only have 1 attribute present.
For example one of my categories - `women > accessories > belts`

has:

```
- 1 price option ($10.00 and above)
- 3 colour options (brown, tan, black)
- 1 brand option (Levi's)
```

How can I hide any filters that only have 1 value present. So in this case instead of the above i would only want:

```
- 3 colour options (brown, tan, black)
```

to show in the layered navigation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

edit the file `/app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/catalog/layer/view.phtml` and replace this line:

```
 <?php if($_filter->getItemsCount()): ?>
```

with

```
 <?php if($_filter->getItemsCount() > 1): ?>
```

I only see one problem with this approach.
If all your filters have only one option they you will still get the section title

```
<p class="block-subtitle"><?php echo $this->__('Shopping Options') ?></p>
```

But this can easily be overcome if you loop through the available filters and see if you have at least one that has the items count bigger than 1.

Comment: Helped in magento2..:)

Comment: Awesome saved my time!!